# Moving objects in javascript (the start of the snake game)

Tags: javascript

Does anyone have an idea how to make these 3 colored squares move around the perimeter of the board, and not like now, i.e. in lines? (lines 57-78) https://codepen.io/diana-larussa/pen/ExgpXzo

```js
function timer() {
    ttl--

    divElement = document.querySelectorAll('div')

    divElement[nr_boxu].style.backgroundColor = "#6d5dfc"
    divElement[nr_boxu].value = 0

    nr_boxu = nr_boxu + 1
    divElement[nr_boxu].style.backgroundColor = "#F25270"
    divElement[nr_boxu+1].style.backgroundColor = "#F25270"
    divElement[nr_boxu+2].style.backgroundColor = "#F25270"

    spanTimer.innerHTML = "TIME: " + ttl
    //if (nr_boxu>gridDOMElement.value-4) stop()

    /*if (divElement[nr_boxu] == gridDOMElement.value - 4) {
        divElement[gridDOMElement.value + 1].style.backgroundColor = "#F25270"
    }*/

    if (ttl == 0) stop()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for each grid size it is possible to generate perimeter sequence of indices and `timer()` function could pick 4 of those indices to update.

For example, in this grid 5x4:

| **0** | **1** | **2** | **3** | **4** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **5** | 6 | 7 | 8 | **9** |
| **10** | 11 | 12 | 13 | **14** |
| **15** | **16** | **17** | **18** | **19** |

`perimeter` array would be: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 14, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 10, 5]` (indices highlighted in bold)

`timer` function will pick 4 indices out of the array, for example `[0, 1, 2, 3]` at the start and will colour element at index 0 with `#6d5dfc` and 1, 2, 3 with `#F25270`.

It will later follow around the perimeter, for example picking 4 elements: `[2, 3, 4, 9]` and colouring element 2 with `#6d5dfc` and 3, 4, 9 with `#F25270` (need to be careful when reaching end of array).

`nr_boxu` seems to be incremented starting from 0 on every `timer()` call.

It can be used to pick 4 elements from `perimeter` array starting from 0 till the end of array.

The following formula - `nr_boxu % perimeter.length` uses [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to keep iterating from 0 till `perimeter.length - 1`.

`perimeter` and `timer` can be built like this:

```
function getPerimeter(cols, rows) {
  let res = [];
  // top line: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
  for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    res.push(i);
  }
  // right line: 9, 14
  for (let i = 1; i < rows - 1; i++) {
    res.push(cols * (i + 1) - 1);
  }
  // bottom line: 19, 18, 17, 16, 15
  for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    res.push(cols * rows - 1 - i);
  }
  // left line: 10, 15
  for (let i = rows - 2; i > 0; i--) {
    res.push(i * cols);
  }
  return res;
}

let perimeter = getPerimeter(numOfColumns, numOfRows);

function timer() {
    ttl--

    const ind1 = perimeter[nr_boxu % perimeter.length];
    const ind2 = perimeter[(nr_boxu + 1) % perimeter.length];
    const ind3 = perimeter[(nr_boxu + 2) % perimeter.length];
    const ind4 = perimeter[(nr_boxu + 3) % perimeter.length];

    divElement = document.querySelectorAll('div')

    divElement[ind1].style.backgroundColor = "#6d5dfc"
    divElement[ind1].value = 0

    nr_boxu = nr_boxu + 1
    divElement[ind2].style.backgroundColor = "#F25270"
    divElement[ind3].style.backgroundColor = "#F25270"
    divElement[ind4].style.backgroundColor = "#F25270"

    spanTimer.innerHTML = "TIME: " + ttl
    //if (nr_boxu>gridDOMElement.value-4) stop()

    /*if (divElement[nr_boxu] == gridDOMElement.value - 4) {
        divElement[gridDOMElement.value + 1].style.backgroundColor = "#F25270"
    }*/

    if (ttl == 0) stop()
}
```